# Why does browser reload of page loads the wrong state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states, `home` and `category`. The app configuration is as follows:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/home').when('','/home');

$stateProvider
    .state('browse', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/'
    })  
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'home': {
                template: "<label>State : {{state}} </label><p>Recommendations</p>",
                    controller: "HomeController"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('category', {
        url: '/category/:categoryName/:catID',
        views: {
            'categories': {
                template: 
                    "<label>State : {{title}}/{{catID}}</label>"+
                    "<div infinite-scroll='fetchMoreProducts(catID,lastPage)' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>"+
                        "<h4 class='well' ng-repeat='p in products'>{{p}}</h4>"+
                    "</div>",
                controller: "CategoriesController", 
            }
        }
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Suppose I am currently on state `category` with URL as `https://.../category/Dairy/11` and I try to reload the page from the browser, the state is not reloaded correctly. I don't know which state is loaded, but I see nothing where `ui-view` should have been there. Now, if I do `console.log($state.current)` it outputs the following in the browser console:

```
Object { name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true }
```

Here is the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/r0QfW4sod00xjrclWtQu?p=preview). After reloading I tried checking `$stateChangeStart` event to trigger a `$state.go()`, but that results in an infinite loop.

Why is it not correctly reloading the same state on which the app was before refresh?

Comment: Having live demo always helps ;)

Comment: I can give you the demo, but is it possible to view the state changes in the address bar with jsFiddle or plunker?

Comment: Yes, sure. You may use this plunker as a starting point: https://plnkr.co/edit/UmDUP1qYnNqFFd8CuG6D?p=preview

Comment: In my case I want to test state changes with browser reload. It is not possible with plunker to test this. Or can I simulate that action somehow?

Comment: Use "Launch preview in a separate window" button. There you can refresh with `F5` or `CTRL+R`

Comment: I have updated the question with the plunk